# Idiomatic way to select a map in vector by a key

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Suppose I have this vector of maps:

```
[{:title "Title1" :id 18347125}
 {:title "Title2" :id 18347123}
 {:title "Title3" :id 18341121}]
```

And I wish to select the map with :id 18347125, how would I do this?

I've tried

```
(for [map maps
      :when (= (:id map) id)]
    map)
```

This feels a bit ugly and returns a sequence of length one, and I want to return just the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the simplest way to write it, but I think this is more clear about your intentions:

```
(->> maps
     (filter #(= (:id %) id))
     first)
```

Comment: All good answers but I'm accepting this as it directly solves my problem.

Answer (score 11):

IMHO, there are several ways to solve your problem, and the definitely idiomatic way is in the realm of taste. This is my solution where I simply translated "to select maps whose `:id` is `1834715`" into Clojure.

```
user> (def xs [{:title "Title1" :id 18347125}
               {:title "Title2" :id 18347123}
               {:title "Title3" :id 18341121}])
#'user/xs

user> (filter (comp #{18347125} :id) xs)
({:title "Title1", :id 18347125})
```

The `:id` keyword is a function that looks up itself in a collection passed to it. The set `#{18347125}` is also a function that tests if a value passed to it equals `18347125`. Using a Clojure set as a predicate function allows for a succinct idiom.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't do what you asked for exactly, but might be useful nonetheless:

```
user=> (group-by :id [{:title "Title1" :id 18347125}
                      {:title "Title2" :id 18347123}
                      {:title "Title3" :id 18341121}])
{18347125 [{:title "Title1" :id 18347125}]
 18347123 [{:title "Title2" :id 18347123}]
 18341121 [{:title "Title3" :id 18341121}]}
```

Now you can simply look the map up by id. Read more about [group-by on clojuredocs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/group-by), its a very useful function.

Note that it puts the maps inside vectors. This is because group-by is designed to handle *grouping* (ie multiple items with the same key):

```
user=> (group-by :id [{:title "Title1" :id 123}
                      {:title "Title2" :id 123}
                      {:title "Title3" :id 18341121}])
{123 [{:title "Title1" :id 123} {:title "Title2" :id 123}]
 18341121 [{:title "Title3" :id 18341121}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to query not just once, but multiple times for maps with specific IDs, I would suggest to make your data types match your use case, i.e. to change the vector into a map:

```
(def maps-by-id (zipmap (map :id maps) maps))
```

So now your IDs are the keys in this new map of maps:

```
user=> (maps-by-id 18347125)
{:title "Title1", :id 18347125}
```